# Is there a good alternative to analog for web server log analysis?

Tags: web-server, log-files, analysis, piwik

I have been using [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/) to analyze the logs of our Apache web server. While analog is quite powerful, I find it quite tedious to set it up correctly to get the information that you want.

My question is: Do you know any (perhaps more "modern") tools to analyze web server log files? Preferably these would be tools running on the web server machine itself, which in my case is a Debian Linux system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've been fairly happy with [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)

They've got a demo page set up [here](http://www.nltechno.com/awstats/awstats.pl?config=destailleur.fr) for a quick example.

Comment: Ubuntu has an awstats package, so I suspect Debian may as well. Makes things nice and easy...

Comment: +1 for awstats.  It just works, and even supports combining load balanced site logs, which is a real plus.

Plus I used it to replace an OLD WebTrends set of reports, and thus far have been able to get more information out of awstats (with some plugins) than I could with WT.

Answer (score 5):

For completenesss, I'll also throw in a suggestion of [Webalizer](http://www.mrunix.net/webalizer/), although it's been a while since I used it last. (My more recent experience has been with the already-mentioned [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: +1 for completeness (I also prefer AWStats to Webalizer)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe try out [piwik](http://piwik.org/) its a Google Analytics clone that easy on the eyes, and has several plugins for adding additional functionality.

demo site can be found here: http://piwik.org/demo/index.php

Comment: Piwik needs its own database; it does not analyse server log files.

Comment: Piwik has a log-importer with which you can import log files from almost any webserver and analyze the data later.

Comment: I like the idea of Piwik, but every time I've thrown real logs at it, it has choked.  Just ran 11M lines for 45 days of logs through it, and the resulting database was ~5GB and even after doing table optimizes and analyzes, it couldn't load any of the widgets within the timeout.  Piwik seems to be more suitable for very small sites.

Answer (score 0):

I like AWStats a lot also, but if you are looking for another suggestion there is also a very modern log analyzer called [Mint](http://haveamint.com/).  It is not free, but the cost is very nominal, $30.

The interface is very sleek, similar to google analytics, but it runs locally and provides real-time statistics.  Also, it has a huge list of [plugins](http://haveamint.com/peppermill/official_pepper/) available.

Comment: Mint does not parse existing webserver log files. It uses a web bug instead, exactly like Google Analytics or Piwik (http://piwik.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I quite like http://www.summary.net/ - it costs, but a free 30 day demo is available.